# Confused on C# Static Member Concept

Tags: c#

I know static Member of a class is a shared member between all instances of that class but how can I use it when an instance is created?
For Example, I have a Class called `Map()` and I would like to keep `MaxZoom` level of all instances of the `Map()` in same level as 18. in following code I am populating the instance by using Object Initializer and setting the Title of each instance but how about `MaxZoom`? where and how I can specify it?

```
void Main()
{
     var map = new Map(){ Title= "Green Coverage"};
     Console.WriteLine(map.Title);
}

public class Map
{
    private static int MaxZoom = 18;
    public string Title {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: You initialize it once and you already did that in your code `MaxZoom = 18`. That's it, you are done, nothing else to do. You can read it by in your class at any point in time. Keep in mind that you defined `MaxZoom` as `private`, **it cannot be accessed outside of the class.**

Comment: You already *do* specify it.  It's `static` so there's only one, and it's defined and specified in line on the class definition.  Are you trying to use it in some way and encountering a problem?

Comment: Static variables can be accessed using the Class name + . + Method name. In your case you could access it like: `Map.MaxZoom = value;`

Comment: You have already set value of static member in class. Since it is private you can not chage from outside of the class. If you make it public you can set it by `Map.MaxZoom = 20`. But you need to be careful while changing it as it may impact behavior of all the instances of the class.

Comment: Does this help?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members#static-members

Comment: It is very clear what OP is asking. Voting to re-open.

Answer (score 2):

> using Object Initializer [I am] setting the `Title` of each instance but how about `MaxZoom`?

You cannot set `MaxZoom` in the object initializer, precisely because it is shared among all instances of the class. Hence, it does not belong to any particular instance.

You already set `MaxZoom` to `18` in the static initializer. If you would like to change it, use `Map.MaxZoom = ...` expression. Since the field is private, you must set it inside of one of `Map`'s method.

**Note:** If you do not plan to change `MaxZoom` at all, make it `readonly` or `const`. If you do plan to change it, using a property provides a better choice.

Comment: Thanks for comment, but this is exactly where I am getting lost. I didn't use the `MaxZoom` in any constructor so how my map will use it?!

Comment: @Suffii : To use `MaxZoom` outside Map class, make it `internal` or `public`. so that you can access with `Map.MaxZoom`

Answer (score 1):

You don't use it as part of an instance.  You use the class definition to reference it.

To change MaxZoom, for example, you would use

```
void Main()
{
  Map.MaxZoom = 30;   // now all maps can only zoom to 30
  var map = new Map(){ Title= "Green Coverage"};
  Console.WriteLine(map.Title);
}
```

As Igor points out below, to get this to work, you'll need to change MaxZoom from `private` to `public`.

If you wanted to, you *could* put in an instance member with the same properties that calls the static one.  This can be useful for common calculations that might be instance-specific.

Comment: What is the access modifier of `MaxZoom` in the OP

Comment: Ooh!  Excellent point, Igor!!!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access static variable from outside class, you need to make `private` access modifier to `internal or public`.

```
public class Map
{
    public static int MaxZoom = 18;
    public string Title {get; set;}
}
```

Static member initialize one time only regardless of number of objects created with that class type.

You can initialize static variable from static constructor as well :

```
public class Map
{
     public static int MaxZoom;
     public string Title { get; set; }

     static Map()
     {
          MaxZoom = 18;
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you already specified the value of the MaxZoom when you defined it in your Map Class. You can only use it inside Map class because it is private.

If you have no intention to change the value of `MaxZoom` in runtime, I'd use `const`